# What is the maximum value of $ \sin x +\sin {2x} (0<x<\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: calculus

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: What is the maximum value of $$ \sin x +\sin {2x} (0<x<\frac{\pi}{2})$$
I have done my work here 
$$f (x)= \sin x +\sin {2x} $$
$$f'(x)= \cos x +2\cos {2x}=\cos x + 4\cos^2 x-2 =0$$
$$\cos x=\frac{1}{8} \left(\sqrt{33}-1\right),\cos x=\frac{1}{8} \left(-\sqrt{33}-1\right)$$
Done...!

Comment: Did you forget to $\cos^{-1}$?

Comment: You found candidates for $\cos x$. One is clearly no good. The question asks for the maximum **value** of $\sin x+\sin(2x)$. And some argument may have to be made that it is indeed the max value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f (x)= \sin x +\sin {2x} $$
$$f'(x)= \cos x +2\cos {2x}=\cos x + 4\cos^2 x-2 = 0 \implies
\cos x = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt {33}}{8}$$

Since we are interested in the maxima only, discard the negative root. In general, $$x = 2k\pi \pm \cos^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{33}-1}{8} = 2k\pi \pm 0.93592946$$

However, in this case $$x = 0.93592946$$

Since $$f''(x) = -(\sin x + 4 \sin 2x)$$ verify that for the above value of $x$, you really have $f''(x) < 0$

In fact, $$f''(0.93592946) = -4.62524$$ and the maxima is $$f(0.93592946) = 1.76017$$

Comment: OP only wants values from 0 to $\pi/2$.